# Functional equivalent of if (p(f(a), f(b)) a else b

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I'm guessing that there must be a better functional way of expressing the following:

```
def foo(i: Any) : Int

if (foo(a) < foo(b)) a else b
```

So in this example `f == foo` and `p == _ < _`. There's bound to be some masterful cleverness in scalaz for this! I can see that using `BooleanW` I can write:

```
p(f(a), f(b)).option(a).getOrElse(b)
```

But I was sure that I would be able to write some code which *only referred to **a** and **b** once*. If this exists it must be on some combination of `Function1W` and something else but scalaz is a bit of a mystery to me!

**EDIT**: *I guess what I'm asking here is not "how do I write this?" but "What is the correct name and signature for such a function and does it have anything to do with FP stuff I do not yet understand like Kleisli, Comonad etc?"*

Comment: I've got a vague feeling this could be expressed nicely with Arrows in Scalaz. Will report back with something more concrete later :)

Comment: `List(a, b) minBy foo` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case it's not in Scalaz:

```
def x[T,R](f : T => R)(p : (R,R) => Boolean)(x : T*) =
  x reduceLeft ((l, r) => if(p(f(l),f(r))) r else l)

scala> x(Math.pow(_ : Int,2))(_ < _)(-2, 0, 1)
res0: Int = -2
```

Alternative with some overhead but nicer syntax.

```
class MappedExpression[T,R](i : (T,T), m : (R,R)) {
  def select(p : (R,R) => Boolean ) = if(p(m._1, m._2)) i._1 else i._2 
}

class Expression[T](i : (T,T)){
  def map[R](f: T => R) = new MappedExpression(i, (f(i._1), f(i._2)))
}

implicit def tupleTo[T](i : (T,T)) = new Expression(i)

scala> ("a", "bc") map (_.length) select (_ < _)
res0: java.lang.String = a
```

Comment: Yes - I realize I could write the function itself. I suppose I wanted to know what the "correct" name for this kind of thing was in FP. Is this to with the Kleisli whatsits? I have no idea!

Comment: I've assumed that already but could not resist to write it anyway. Kleisli whatsits is just white noise for me.

Comment: Give `x` a descriptive name and I might even accept your answer!

Comment: It may be better this way: `(a, b) map (f(_)) x (p(_,_))`.

Comment: @Thomas - but there's no way I can see that you could write x in such a way as to allow this syntax. How would that work?

Comment: I added it as an alternative. There is still some room for improving the naming of the methods.

Comment: Ah - I thought you were saying this was possible with the original method definition. Awesome answer!

Comment: Now you can define `("a", "bc") -> ( _.length) | (_ < _)`. Or some other even more cryptic version.

Comment: I went a long way starting from your type signature, through Haskell, and then got all the way back to your solution. Only, on the trip, your `map` got renamed to `on`.

Comment: @Daniel +1 for map -> on and the anonymous classes.

Comment: @Thomas the combination of anonymous classes and implicits result in reflection, which makes the combination a bad choice most of the time. I only used it to keep the type signatures as close as possible to the original.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that Arrows or any other special type of computation can be useful here. Afterall, you're calculating with normal values and you can usually lift a *pure* computation that into the special type of computation (using `arr` for arrows or `return` for monads).

However, one very simple arrow is `arr a b` is simply a function `a -> b`. You could then use arrows to split your code into more primitive operations. However, there is probably no reason for doing that and it only makes your code more complicated.

You could for example lift the call to `foo` so that it is done separately from the comparison. Here is a simiple definition of arrows in F# - it declares `***` and `>>>` arrow combinators and also `arr` for turning pure functions into arrows:

```
type Arr<'a, 'b> = Arr of ('a -> 'b)
let arr f = Arr f
let ( *** ) (Arr fa) (Arr fb) = Arr (fun (a, b) -> (fa a, fb b))
let ( >>> ) (Arr fa) (Arr fb) = Arr (fa >> fb)
```

Now you can write your code like this:

```
let calcFoo = arr <| fun a -> (a, foo a)    
let compareVals = arr <| fun ((a, fa), (b, fb)) -> if fa < fb then a else b

(calcFoo *** calcFoo) >>> compareVals
```

The `***` combinator takes two inputs and runs the first and second specified function on the first, respectively second argument. `>>>` then composes this arrow with the one that does comparison.

But as I said - there is probably no reason at all for writing this.

Comment: I understand almost nothing of this answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

Here's the Arrow based solution, implemented with Scalaz. This requires trunk.

You don't get a huge win from using the arrow abstraction with plain old functions, but it is a good way to learn them before moving to Kleisli or Cokleisli arrows.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def mod(n: Int)(x: Int) = x % n
def mod10 = mod(10) _
def first[A, B](pair: (A, B)): A = pair._1
def selectBy[A](p: (A, A))(f: (A, A) => Boolean): A = if (f.tupled(p)) p._1 else p._2
def selectByFirst[A, B](f: (A, A) => Boolean)(p: ((A, B), (A, B))): (A, B) =
  selectBy(p)(f comap first) // comap adapts the input to f with function first.

val pair = (7, 16)

// Using the Function1 arrow to apply two functions to a single value, resulting in a Tuple2
((mod10 &&& identity) apply 16) assert_≟ (6, 16)

// Using the Function1 arrow to perform mod10 and identity respectively on the first and second element of a `Tuple2`.
val pairs = ((mod10 &&& identity) product) apply pair
pairs assert_≟ ((7, 7), (6, 16))

// Select the tuple with the smaller value in the first element.
selectByFirst[Int, Int](_ < _)(pairs)._2 assert_≟ 16

// Using the Function1 Arrow Category to compose the calculation of mod10 with the
// selection of desired element.
val calc = ((mod10 &&& identity) product) ⋙ selectByFirst[Int, Int](_ < _)
calc(pair)._2 assert_≟ 16
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I looked up [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) for a type signature like the one in [Thomas Jung's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149311/thomas-jung) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295013/functional-equivalent-of-if-pfa-fb-a-else-b/2295181#2295181), and there is [`on`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-Function.html#v:on). This is what I searched for:

```
(a -> b) -> (b -> b -> Bool) -> a -> a -> a
```

Where `(a -> b)` is the equivalent of `foo`, `(b -> b -> Bool)` is the equivalent of `<`. Unfortunately, the signature for `on` returns something else:

```
(b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
```

This is almost the same, if you replace `c` with `Bool` and `a` in the two places it appears, respectively.

So, right now, I suspect it doesn't exist. It occured to me that there's a more general type signature, so I tried it as well:

```
(a -> b) -> ([b] -> b) -> [a] -> a
```

This one yielded nothing.

**EDIT:**

Now I don't think I was that far at all. Consider, for instance, this:

```
Data.List.maximumBy (on compare length) ["abcd", "ab", "abc"]
```

The function `maximumBy` signature is `(a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a`, which, combined with `on`, is pretty close to what you originally specified, given that `Ordering` is has three values -- almost a boolean! :-)

So, say you wrote `on` in Scala:

```
def on[A, B, C](f: ((B, B) => C), g: A => B): (A, A) => C = (a: A, b: A) => f(g(a), g(b))
```

The you could write `select` like this:

```
def select[A](p: (A, A) => Boolean)(a: A, b: A) = if (p(a, b)) a else b
```

And use it like this:

```
select(on((_: Int) < (_: Int), (_: String).length))("a", "ab")
```

Which really works better with currying and dot-free notation. :-) But let's try it with implicits:

```
implicit def toFor[A, B](g: A => B) = new { 
  def For[C](f: (B, B) => C) = (a1: A, a2: A) => f(g(a1), g(a2)) 
}
implicit def toSelect[A](t: (A, A)) = new { 
  def select(p: (A, A) => Boolean) = t match { 
    case (a, b) => if (p(a, b)) a else b 
  } 
}
```

Then you can write

```
("a", "ab") select (((_: String).length) For (_ < _))
```

Very close. I haven't figured any way to remove the type qualifier from there, though I suspect it is possible. I mean, without going the way of Thomas answer. But maybe that *is* the way. In fact, I think `on (_.length) select (_ < _)` reads better than `map (_.length) select (_ < _)`.

Comment: There was a question about the 'on' function and Scala already. But I could not find it again. It's not exactly an easily searchable word.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to compose `on` so that it had "access" to the original data. The issue being that this question is a "special case" for a predicate whereas `on` is more general

Comment: @oxbow Both the `on` and the `For` -- which is nothing more than an inverted `on`, to take advantage of type inference -- are particular strict about the data types. Only `select` is bound to `Pair` and `Boolean`. What would be the more general case?

Answer (score 1):

This expression can be written very elegantly in [Factor programming language](http://factorcode.org/) - a language where function composition is *the* way of doing things, and most code is written in point-free manner. The stack semantics and row polymorphism facilitates this style of programming. This is what the solution to your problem will look like in Factor:

```
# We find the longer of two lists here. The expression returns { 4 5 6 7 8 }
{ 1 2 3 } { 4 5 6 7 8 } [ [ length ] bi@ > ] 2keep ?

# We find the shroter of two lists here. The expression returns { 1 2 3 }.
{ 1 2 3 } { 4 5 6 7 8 } [ [ length ] bi@ < ] 2keep ?
```

Of our interest here is the combinator [`2keep`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-2keep,kernel.html). It is a "preserving dataflow-combinator", which means that it retains its inputs after the given function is performed on them.

---

Let's try to translate (sort of) this solution to Scala.

First of all, we define an arity-2 preserving combinator.

```
scala> def keep2[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C)(a: A, b: B) = (f(a, b), a, b)
keep2: [A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C)(a: A, b: B)(C, A, B)
```

And an `eagerIf` combinator. `if` being a control structure cannot be used in function composition; hence this construct.

```
scala> def eagerIf[A](cond: Boolean, x: A, y: A) = if(cond) x else y
eagerIf: [A](cond: Boolean, x: A, y: A)A
```

Also, the [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v%3aon) combinator. Since it clashes with a method with the same name from Scalaz, I'll name it `upon` instead.

```
scala> class RichFunction2[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C) {
     |   def upon[D](g: D => A)(implicit eq: A =:= B) = (x: D, y: D) => f(g(x), g(y))
     | }
defined class RichFunction2

scala> implicit def enrichFunction2[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C) = new RichFunction2(f)
enrichFunction2: [A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C)RichFunction2[A,B,C]
```

And now put this machinery to use!

```
scala> def length: List[Int] => Int = _.length
length: List[Int] => Int

scala> def smaller: (Int, Int) => Boolean = _ < _
smaller: (Int, Int) => Boolean

scala> keep2(smaller upon length)(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 5)) |> Function.tupled(eagerIf)
res139: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> def greater: (Int, Int) => Boolean = _ > _
greater: (Int, Int) => Boolean

scala> keep2(greater upon length)(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 5)) |> Function.tupled(eagerIf)
res140: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)
```

This approach does not look particularly elegant in Scala, but at least it shows you one more way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice-ish way of doing this with `on` and `Monad`, but Scala is unfortunately very bad at point-free programming. Your question is basically: "can I reduce the number of points in this program?"

Imagine if `on` and `if` were differently curried and tupled:

```
def on2[A,B,C](f: A => B)(g: (B, B) => C): ((A, A)) => C = {
  case (a, b) => f.on(g, a, b)
}
def if2[A](b: Boolean): ((A, A)) => A = {
  case (p, q) => if (b) p else q
}
```

Then you could use the reader monad:

```
on2(f)(_ < _) >>= if2
```

The Haskell equivalent would be:

```
on' (<) f >>= if'
  where on' f g = uncurry $ on f g
        if' x (y,z) = if x then y else z
```

Or...

```
flip =<< flip =<< (if' .) . on (<) f
  where if' x y z = if x then y else z
```

Comment: Can you please provide a Haskell equivalent as well?

Comment: Aw man, that looks gnarly. Thanks for fulfilling the request though. +1!